# asp.net transform launchSettings.json by build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, buildconfiguration, environments

I am working on a prototype for an asp.net 5 site and I see that Microsoft pushes us to use the [Hosting:Environment environment variable](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) to determine what environment (Development, Stage, Production) the application is in as well as other environment variables and what authentication type the site runs. These values are then stored in the launchSettings.json file in the properties folder. You can then grab the environment from the startup class using.

```
env.IsEnvironment("SelectedEnvironment");
```

The problem I have is that my site has many different environments and some of these environments are anonymous authentication and others are windows authentication. I would prefer not to have to go in to the debug section of the site properties and change the Hosting:Environment and authentication type everytime I am switching to a different environment. In the past I would create a build configuration for each environment and then use tranforms on the config files for each environment. This would allow me to change environments in the build. Unfortunatly launchSettings.json does not appear to allow me to transform it based on the selected build configuration.

Am I missing a way to transform the launchSettings.json file or is there another way to accomplish this without having to hand type the environment and select the auth type each time I want to change environments? I know I can run them from the command line and put the variables in there, but I am trying to run this and publish from VS.